# Python DNS response with Scapy

Tags: python, networking, dns, scapy

I am trying to respond to DNS requests using Python, the response packet is being sent out using scapy, but it does not reach the client/requestor. On running tcpdump, I noticed that the DNS response via scapy resulted in

```
[bad udp cksum 0x4c91 -> 0x8abd!]
```

So I was wondering if that could be the reason why the client/requestor was not able to receive the DNS response. If that is the case, how can I solve this problem?

If that is not the reason, then I am really lost..

DNS_Res.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from scapy.all import *

def dnsRes(pkt):

    # print pkt[IP].src
    ip = pkt.getlayer(IP)
    dns = pkt.getlayer(DNS)
    return IP(dst=ip.src, src=ip.dst)/UDP(dport=ip.sport,sport=ip.dport)/DNS(id=dns.id,qd=dns.qd,an=DNSRR(rrname=dns.qd.qname, type='TXT', ttl=10,rdata='ransom'))



def main():
    while 1:
        # sniff(filter="udp and port 53", prn=dnsRes)
        a=sniff(filter="port 53",count=1,promisc=1)
        if not a[0].haslayer(DNS) or a[0].qr:
            continue
        send(dnsRes(a[0]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Just a tip, about the problem `[bad udp cksum 0x4c91 -> 0x8abd!]` you can let scapy calculate the checksum by doing `a[0][UDP].chksum=None`  before sending it